# Populate form with cookies in Facelets page

Tags: jsf

Filling some inputs of a form in a JSP page using Servlets is quite straightforward: set attribute value of the input to the value of the cookie:

```
<input id="id" type="text" value="${cookie.name.value}">
```

and the Servlet just reads the parameters from request and assign them to the bean.

Now I am using JSF 2.2 + Facelets and in this case the `value` attribute is directly linked to the bean:

```
<h:inputText value="#{Bean.property}"/>
```

and there is no need to write a Servlet.

I guess I can just use an intermediate backing bean and assign the values to the real one when processing the form submission but it does not feel right.

What is the best way to do this?

UPDATE

I want to clarify my intentions:

The form is big, and part of it is just gathering user data (name, telephone, email address, etc).

I don't want to implement a sign up / sign in system because it is not going to be used frequently and it is only for a reduced (but not fixed) number of users. So it is better to make the user fill its data everytime than making the user sign up in our system, with all the added complications: the user has to remember login details that will be used maybe once a month or even less, we have to implement the login system, add security...

But, in order to make filling the form easier, I think is a good idea to store user data in cookies, and the next time the user needs to use the form, the part of it that just ask for user data (which it would not have changed, probably) is filled automatically.

So, the idea is:

1. The first time, the user fills the whole form: the data we actually need and the user information for contact purposes: name, telephone, email address, etc.
2. The next time, given that the user is on the same computer, the part of the form that gathers user information for contact purposes is already filled using the cookies. The user can edit contact details if needed before submitting the form, of course.

In summary, I can't use a resource bundle with defaults, because it's different for every user, and implementing a login system is quite overkill. That's why I want to use cookies to automatically fill part of the form, but I don't know what's the best way to do this using JSF.

Comment: I am asking how to set the default value of an input field to the one stored in a cookie in a Facelets page.

Comment: *"Filling some inputs of a form in a JSP page using Servlets is quite straightforward: set attribute value of the input to the value of the cookie"* Here you're implying that filling input values from cookies is "normal practice". This is absolutely not true. On the contrary, this is a very strange approach. I'd say that this was wrong in first place and you'd better stop doing that.

Comment: Still, you're looking in the wrong direction. You can use a *single cookie* as a token, that identifies a bunch of user-specific data items, that will be stored in a database. Given a specific cookie, your application should pull the data from your DB and store in your backing bean, from which the fields in your form would be populated. Should the user then change the value of those fields, you simply resubmit the modified DTO.